# Numpy: can not read dataset headers

Tags: python, numpy, names

My code looks like

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

train = genfromtxt('/Users/hhimanshu/Downloads/dataset/digitrecognizer/train.csv',
                   delimiter=',', names=True)
```

and the `train.csv` has data like

```
label,pixel0,pixel1,pixel2,pixel3, .....
1,0,0,0, ...
```

when I do

```
train.names
```

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-dea84e8fe1f5> in <module>()
      4 print 'size(Number of elements in array) = ', train.size
      5 # print 'data type = ', train.dtype
----> 6 train.names

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'names'
```

Also the shape seem incorrect to me

```
shape(Tuple of array dimensions) =  (42000,)
dimension(Number of array dimensions) =  1
size(Number of elements in array) =  42000
```

I know that I have **785** columns and **2** dimensions(it says 1 here)

What is that I am not doing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad,

`ndarray` has no attribute called `names`
I can refer columns as `train['labels']` and get the data

Comment: sure, but only after 2 days as per SO, I will do that

Answer (score 0):

To get the columns names you can use: `train.dtype.names`

This will only work if `train` is a record (structured) array.